# Amazon Mechanical Turk: Random Questions in One Qualification Type

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am using [`CreateQualificationType`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_CreateQualificationTypeOperation.html) operation to create a new qualification type in MTurk, so that I can require this qualification test in my HITs.

Now I have a set of questions for this qualification test, but I only want MTurk workers who request this qualification test to answer just **a small part** of those questions, and different works answer **different** questions randomly. I didn't find any useful answers in [AWS Document about Qualifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMechanicalTurkRequester/Concepts_QualificationsArticle.html). Is there a method to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible. A Qualification test can only be setup using QuestionForm XML, which does not allow randomization of any kind. The most commonly recommended alternative is to create a HIT with the content you want and then assign qualification scores to workers based upon their responses to the HIT. Less than ideal, but the only option.

Answer (score 2):

a piece of cake, actually.  what you need to do is create the question xml file inside a loop and then create the hit from that question xml. In the example below I hand crafted a question xml and verified that it worked on the sandbox.  then I split the question xml file into parts a,b,c corresponding to the parts that did not change, then in my loop I write the xml code to a text file.

- parta
- part of the question that changes, in this case the image
- partb
  part of the question that changes, in this case the multiple choice
- partc

at the conclusion of the progress I have a valid xml file that I open and use in the create hit.  Now I know this question is about a qualification, but the idea is exactly the same.

```py
for hit_number in range(how_many):
    print(hit_number)
    my_emotions = sample(emotion_names,5)
    my_emoji = sample(emoji_numbers,1)
    HIT_image = <a url on S3 is convenient>

    f_out = open('data/dynamic_question.xml', 'w')
    f_out.write(parta)
    f_out.close()

    f_out = open('data/dynamic_question.xml', 'a')
    f_out.write('    <DataURL>' + HIT_image + '</DataURL>' + '\n')
    f_out.write(partb)

    for emotion in my_emotions:
        f_out.write('          <Selection>' + '\n')
        f_out.write('            <SelectionIdentifier>' + emotion + '</SelectionIdentifier>' + '\n')
        f_out.write('            <Text>' + emotion.capitalize() + '</Text>' + '\n')
        f_out.write('          </Selection>' + '\n')

    f_out.write(partc)
    f_out.close()

    with open("data/dynamic_question.xml") as f:
        question = f.read()

    # Create the HIT 
    response = client.create_hit(
```

Comment: Would you please complete your example? It looks like you left out some code at the end.